# How can I measure the charge current into a small LiPo battery?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium, monitor

I have a SparkFun [USB LiPoly](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12711) charger that by (default) is set at 500mA.
If I try and measure the charge current with my DIY multimeters, the charging LED goes out and the meter reports zero current?

I guess this is because of the multimeter's internal series Vsense resistor confusing the onboard MCP73831 controller chip?

If this assumption is correct, can anyone suggest a DIY method method of measuring small Lithium battery charge currents?

Comment: What current range are you using on the multimeter? I'd assume the sense resistor value should be tiny on the 10A range.

Comment: please add a schematic showing how you connect the multimeter. I suspect that you are doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the 10A range does have the lowest sense resistor (0.1ohm) but on that range the resolution is only +or- 0.01A. The 200mA range  (on many meters that I have checked) averages 2ohm but even at that value it seems to be sufficient to cause the charger to miscalculate the battery voltage and turn off?

Answer (score 1):

Add a low value resistor and measure the voltage drop across that.